Person holding two persons hanging over the edge and centre of mass inconsistency
Imagine a person holding the leg of the person in front that also holds the person in front of him. (over the edge like in MI4, assume centre of mass of second person with feet still on the floor is over the edge as well)

Image taken from: https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/tom-cruise-mission-impossible-ghost-protocol-gregg-smrz-160029441.html

The image I've drawn above shows the situation analyzed using two different approaches. In the first approach I consider only the two centre of masses of the two bodies. The person inside the building needs to pull them with a force equalling the sum of the two weights so that they do not fall. In the second sceneraio however, considering only the part of the second person's body that is hanging out of the building, the weight pulling down is that of the 3rd person (Tom Cruise) and only the part of the second person that hangs outside from the building. Why do these two different approaches to analyzing the problem yield different results?
We could also imagine a heavy chain that is hanging over the edge with one part of it in the building instead of this scenario.

So where's the beef? What's the inconsistency? Put the numbers and symbols in text; not just scribbles on a paper scan.

You also should consider the torque: the man inside has his left foot against the inner wall, his right foot probably against some other part so there are two pivots.

If we consider the COM of the entire second person then his legs are also accounted for. If we consider only the part hanging out of the window, then we discard the weight of the legs.

Person 1 only has to provide enough force to support the weight of the part of Person 2 that is over the edge (plus the weight of Person 3 if we are including them too). The weight of the rest of Person 2 (the part that is not over the edge) is supported by the normal force that the floor exerts on Person 2.
In some scenarios we can treat an extended body as if it were a single point mass at its centre of mass, but this is not one of them.

But if we consider the centre of mass of the entire second person then we get a different result because the centre of mass would also include the persons legs?

@LEXORAI Which just shows that in this scenario you cannot treat the second person as a single point mass at their centre of mass. This is a simplification which should be carefully justified whenever you use it, and in this case it cannot be justified.

How do we know when it can or cannot be justified? If part of body is on the building it cannot be justified?

@LEXORAI The COM simplification only applies to rigid bodies. In this case we are not treating the second person as a rigid body (otherwise they would be a plank).

The person in the middle hanging over the window ledge is not a rigid rod, so the person inside the building can not use his own weight vertically to stop them falling. All he has to do prevent them falling, is prevent himself moving horizontally, by for example bracing his feet on the bottom of the inside of the window. As you mentioned this can be analysed by imagining the second and third persons are a heavy chain. You cannot use the chain as a lever to lever the chain up using the weight of the first person. He has to pull the chain horizontally inside the building to pull the chain up vertically outside the building. In reality the middle person is not as flexible as a chain. There is some vertical leverage going on. The inside lever is the length from his waist to his feet. The outside lever is the distance from the window to where his hands are and this is shorter so there is some mechanical advantage. This allows the weight of a single person inside to overcome the weight of one and half persons outside.
